# What are the benefits of bounded type parameters?

Tags: java, generics

See below example,What are the benefits of bounded type parameters comparing `f(U u)` to `g(I obj)`?

```
interface I {}
class A {
    public static <U extends I> void f(U u){ }
    public static void g(I obj) { }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There aren't any, for this particular case.  You can execute exactly the same operations on `U` (knowing that `U extends I`) as you can on an `I`.

More often you'll see cases for which it makes an actual difference:

```
public static <U extends I> void f(Collection<U> collection)
```

or, more generally, the bounded type parameter being used as a parameter for another generic type.

Comment: Thanks.But what are the benefits of your example comparing to `public static void f(Collection<I> collection)` ?

Comment: @Don You can't pass a `Collection<Integer>` into a method that expects a `Collection<Number>`.

Comment: In the given example `Collection<? extends I>` would have been sufficient too.

Comment: Of course.  But `f(Collection<U> collection, U something)` might be a thing.  There are plenty of variations.